# How to programmatically export template list in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to programmatically export the list of templates in an EA project.
Currently I can get that list with the SQL scratch pad:

> SELECT DocName AS TemplateName, Author AS TemplateLocation
> FROM t_document
> WHERE DocType = 'SSDOCSTYLE'

However, if I run this query within a script it doesn't work cause it is missing the elementID.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few steps you need to to

- Execute your query using `Repository.SQLQuery()`
- Parse the resulting xml string using an xml library
- Loop over the nodes in the xml doc to get the actual result
- Export the results to a file

Some snippets from my [github VBScript library](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library/) that can help:
With these functions you get a two dimensional array containing the results of your query.

```
function getArrayFromQuery(sqlQuery)
    dim xmlResult
    xmlResult = Repository.SQLQuery(sqlQuery)
    getArrayFromQuery = convertQueryResultToArray(xmlResult)
end function

'converts the query results from Repository.SQLQuery from xml format to a two dimensional array of strings
Public Function convertQueryResultToArray(xmlQueryResult)
    Dim arrayCreated
    Dim i 
    i = 0
    Dim j 
    j = 0
    Dim result()
    Dim xDoc 
    Set xDoc = CreateObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument" )
    'load the resultset in the xml document
    If xDoc.LoadXML(xmlQueryResult) Then        
        'select the rows
        Dim rowList
        Set rowList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Row")

        Dim rowNode 
        Dim fieldNode
        arrayCreated = False
        'loop rows and find fields
        For Each rowNode In rowList
            j = 0
            If (rowNode.HasChildNodes) Then
                'redim array (only once)
                If Not arrayCreated Then
                    ReDim result(rowList.Length, rowNode.ChildNodes.Length)
                    arrayCreated = True
                End If
                For Each fieldNode In rowNode.ChildNodes
                    'write f
                    result(i, j) = fieldNode.Text
                    j = j + 1
                Next
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next
        'make sure the array has a dimension even is we don't have any results
        if not arrayCreated then
            ReDim result(0, 0)
        end if
    end if
    convertQueryResultToArray = result
End Function
```